# Потокобезопасное создание объекта локального статического мьютекса?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

Предположим, требуется организовать защиту произвольного кода локальным статическим мьютексом:

```
void MyClass::myMethod() {
    static QMutex mutex;

    mutex.lock();
    // защищённый код ...
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Насколько мне известно, если вместо `QMutex` будет иной локальный статический тип (например, `QString`), то запросто может случиться "гонка" и, скажем, два конкурирующих потока создадут две копии объекта.

Несмотря на то, что в справке Qt для `QMutex` указано, что все методы являются потокобезопасными, нет уверенности, что заявленное справедливо и для его конструктора.

Будет ли в контексте `MyClass::myMethod()` создание объекта мьютекса при первом обращении потокобезопасным?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @kff, то есть, как я понимаю, пишут, что вроде как безопасно многопоточно создавать статические локальные переменные? Вообще любого типа, а не только мьютексы? На Хабре при этом [писали](https://habrahabr.ru/post/118390/) другое. Может, правда, уже устарело?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начиная с C++11 инициализация статических переменных потокобезопасна ([§6.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)):

> Otherwise such a variable is initialized the
>   first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is
>   considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. If
>   the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
>   is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control
>   enters the declaration.  **If control enters the declaration
>   concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent
>   execution shall wait for completion of the initialization**.

---

Для более ранних стандартов это не гарантировалось, хотя некоторые компиляторы обеспечивали такую защиту (например, GCC).

[Рассмотрим](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qmutex.cpp#n182) конструктор `QMutex`:

```
QMutex::QMutex(RecursionMode mode)
{
    d_ptr.store(mode == Recursive ? new QRecursiveMutexPrivate : 0);
}
```

Qt широко использует идиому Pimpl, `d_ptr` как раз и является указателем на реализацию и имеет тип `QBasicAtomicPointer<QMutexData>`. При многопоточном доступе к конструктору могут возникнуть случаи, когда объект  `QRecursiveMutexPrivate` будет сконструирован несколько раз, что приведет к утечкам памяти. Если мьютекс нерекурсивный, то конструктор потокобезопасен.

Другая, более серьезная, проблема связана с `race condition`: например, два потока `A` и `B` начинают инициализацию переменной `mutex`, поток `A` завершает инициализацию и вызывает функцию `lock()`, управление передается потоку `B`, который в свою очередь завершает инициализацию, что приводит в итоге к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Не вполне понял. С одной стороны: "the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization", а с другой стороны Вы пишете, что поток `B`, как и поток `A`, тоже завершает инициализацию переменной `mutex`. Означает ли это, что поток `B` всё-таки не будет ждать, пока `A` полностью не сконструирует объект `mutex`?

Comment: @alexis031182 Все что после цитаты применительно к более ранним страндартам. Попробовал визуально отделить

Comment: Увидел теперь, спасибо большое.